# kubernetes pod name rule

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In process install of my kubernetes cluster, I ran into the problem of naming pods. 
How to add to the name of the container the name of the node on which it is was deployed?

Exemple of my Daemon Set yaml:

```
.... 
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      name: CONTAINER-NAME-HOST-NAME
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming convention falls under the [RFC 1123 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-2) of a DNS label.

`Starting from v1.4 names must not be longer than 253 characters.`

`Name should be expressed by the regular expression: [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?`

`Underscore "_" is not allowed.`

You can see applicable code in GitHub for [checking container names](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/53a9d106c4aabcd550cc32ae4e8004f32fb0ae7b/pkg/api/validation/validation.go#L280), [defining acceptable names](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/7f2d0c0f710617ef1f5eec4745b23e0d3f360037/pkg/util/validation.go#L26).

Comment: Name in question was be like example.
I need that the name be of the form - namepod-hostname

Comment: Use all small letters, I think there is a rule saying first and last character should be small letter.

Comment: Crou, I want to include the name of my host in the container name

Comment: I think this is not possible, you would need to use for example [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to make flexible and configurable deployments.